# tortoisehg import module error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I get an error when i running my tortoisehg - python : **`"*** failed to import extension hgcr-gui-qt: cannot import name updatedir"`**. *how to correct it ?*

Comment: Template for you: I get an error when i running my tortoisehg *version X* on *OS name X, version X, type X*, when I try *action X* - *full error message here*

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS, all traces of this error show us summer of 2011 and THG 2.0.* and THG 1.9 and status FIXED

- [#30131 (tortoisehg 2.0.4 won't start with mercurial 1.9.x) – MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30131)
- [hg 1.9 breaks thg 2.0.5?](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2011-July/038878.html)
- [tortoisehg: TortoiseHG cannot start](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635591)

Maybe, it's time to update (TortoiseHg version 2.3.1 with Mercurial-2.1.1, Python-2.6.6, PyQt-4.8.6, Qt-4.7.4 is **latest today**) and check error again (and ask **good** question, if error still exist in your case)?